# How can I transmit to Weapon class a image URL

Tags: java

I need to transmit the url to Weapon class but it gives me error:

> Cannot reference 'Object.Class' before supertype constructor has been
>   called

```
private class Weapon{
            private int range;
            private Image image;

            Weapon(int range, String imgUrl){
                this.range = range;
                image = new Image(imgUrl);
            }
    }

    private class Knife extends Weapon{
         Knife() {
                super(5, getClass().getResource("knife.png").toExternalForm());
         }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that your Knife class needs a constructor with range and image URL; your Weapon class needs a default constructor.  Your code will not even compile.

Comment: But I need default value for image url "knife.png"

Comment: Yes, I know.  See my answer below.

Comment: You could replace getClass() with the `Knife.class` literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots wrong with this code.

I have no idea why both of these are private.

As Luke Lee so astutely points out, you can't call `getClass()` as you do.  Think of another way to manage it, like giving the name of a resource and letting the super class resolve it.

Weapon.java:

```
private class Weapon {

    protected int range;  // units?  feet?  miles?  furlongs?
    protected Image image;

    public Weapon(int range, String imageName) {
        this.range = range;
        image = new Image(this.getClass().getResource(imageName).toExternalForm());  // what happens if imgUrl is null?  Not a URL?
    }
}
```

Knife.java:

```
private class Knife extends Weapon {

    // Magic numbers are bad; these are more self documenting.
    public static final int DEFAULT_RANGE = 5;
    public static final String DEFAULT_IMAGE_URL = "knife.png";

    public Knife() { this(DEFAULT_RANGE, DEFAULT_IMAGE_URL); }

    public Knife(int range, String imageName) {
        super(range, imageName);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is you cannot reference members from parent class before the super constructor finishes.

Comment: I don't think my code does.  Do you mean the getClass() call?  You might be right about that.

Comment: `getClass` is a member of `Object`

Comment: Yes, you're right.  If I were doing this with Spring it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Weapon and Knife are inner classes. The same error in Knife.

Comment: I think the way I rearranged it should work.  Let the super class figure out the resource.